# Error: "Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context"

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, dbcontext

Looked through related posts but still having difficulty.  Here is my code:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"].AsInt();
var accountNum = Request.QueryString["accountnum"];

var orderIDs = new List<OrderID>();

// Order IDs are in the form: OrderNum-OrderLine[,...]
// e.g. orderids=41417-6,36703-1

foreach (var orderID in Request.QueryString["orderids"].Split(',')) {
    var components = orderID.Split('-');
    orderIDs.Add(new OrderID() {
        OrderNum = components[0].AsInt(), 
        OrderLine = components[1].AsInt()
    });
}

var dbContext = new TelecomEntities();
var assignedLines = dbContext.LineAssignments
    .Where(a => orderIDs
        .Any(i => a.OrderNum == i.OrderNum && a.OrderLine == i.OrderLine))
    .ToList();
```

When running this, I get the error: *Unable to create a constant value of type 'OrderID'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*

From what I've read in other posts, I can't perform the query because `orderIDs` is not in the `dbContent` context.

**Edit:** OrderID Class

```
public class OrderID
{
    public int OrderNum { get; set; }
    public int OrderLine { get; set; }

    public OrderID() { }
}
```

Comment: Where is your declaration of the OrderID class?

Comment: It's in the `App_Code` folder in `OrderID.cs`

Comment: Sorry, I meant, could you show us your declaration of OrderID class.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that EF can't convert your comparison to an OrderID object into SQL.  One option may be to leave the Order IDs as strings:

```
var id = Request.QueryString["id"].AsInt();
var accountNum = Request.QueryString["accountnum"];

string[] orderIDs;

// Order IDs are in the form: OrderNum-OrderLine[,...]
// e.g. orderids=41417-6,36703-1

orderIDs = Request.QueryString["orderids"].Split(',');

var dbContext = new TelecomEntities();
var assignedLines = dbContext.LineAssignments
    .Where(a => orderIDs
        .Any(on => on.Equals(a.OrderNum + "-" + a.OrderLine))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting it's the AsInt (which I have never seen before, but I see it's part of WebPages).

Do you get the error inside the foreach?  If so, try this instead:

```
        foreach (var orderID in testOrderIDs.Split(','))
        {
            var components = orderID.Split('-');
            orderIDs.Add(new OrderID()
            {
                OrderNum = int.Parse(components[0]),
                OrderLine = int.Parse(components[1])
            });
        }
```

Comment: The line in which I assign `assignedLines` is throwing the error.